# Is the framework AMFPHP a bridge between flash and PHP? How?

Tags: flash, amfphp

Please explain about the connectivity of data using AMFPHP between the flash frontend and the mysql database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer:-

AMFPHP allows an enabled flash or silverlight or javascript app to call functions and methods declared in the PHP backend.

So if your backend php is returning a value, the flash/sl/js can pick it up and run with it.

Answer (score 4):

It is basically a translation library..  converting PHP methods/object into Actionscript Objects - and visa/versa.   It is very similar to using json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a training video (about ActionScript binary interactions to the PHP back end to MYSQL).

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=78

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=79